# python reduce with floating point error

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, list-comprehension, reduce

When manually calculating the variance of a list of floats, I used "reduce" but found it was slightly off from what I expected (given numpy.var).  I then recalculated it using a list comprehension, and got exactly the value I expected.

```
sumSqrdReduce = reduce((lambda total, val: total+(val - mean)**2), lst)
sumSqrdComprehension = sum([(val-mean)**2 for val in lst])
```

An example list that demonstrates this problem:

```
lst = [0.53839998, 4.36650467, 3.64258786, 3.62987329, -0.33371547, 10.16436997, 3.11141481, 4.62991016, 0.72292498, -2.9477603, 4.0144724, 7.14428721, -3.05925725, 4.83175576, 5.55112354, 5.03295696, -2.40226829, 1.87662003, -1.02187228, 5.25553533, 1.54985611, 2.71460086, 0.83336707, -3.3935002, 3.88551682, -2.47155389, 1.76985117, 3.57110149, -5.17191153, 4.80879124, -0.97037815, 0.99500531, -0.22062183, 9.96261967, 3.31320864, 0.39606156, -2.71492665, 0.31085669, -1.82838686, 0.38113291, 2.7265862, 6.46300302, 3.11995554, 0.15073258, 12.03547416, 4.82310128, 2.43649615, 3.2195886, 2.84891094, 9.75191341]
```

With the above list (mean = 2.4008863134):

```
sumSqrdReduce = 671.241430925
sumSqrdComprehension = 674.171886287
```

Am I performing the reduce incorrectly?  Or is this a generic 'floating point accumulation error,' and if so, why do the two methods not replicate the same floating point inaccuracies?  I would expect any discrepancies from 'truth' to be the same with each method, and hopefully not so drastically different.

Comment: add a third argument, the initial value, of 0.0 to your reduce and you'll find it produces the correct answer.

Comment: Ha, that did it!  How strange that it needs to be initialized to 0... thanks @IrmendeJong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are indeed performing the reduction incorrectly. You're taking the first element of `lst` as the initial `total`, without taking its squared deviation from the mean.

The `(val - mean)**2` part of your `reduce` is more conceptually appropriate for a `map`, if you really want to use the traditional functional programming functions:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda x: (x-mean)**2, lst))
```

Or you could specify an initial accumulator value of 0.0:

```
reduce((lambda total, val: total+(val - mean)**2), lst, 0.0)
```

Since you've tagged your question NumPy, here's how you'd do it for a NumPy array `arr` of values, if for some reason you wanted to avoid the built-in `numpy.var`:

```
numpy.sum((arr-mean)**2)
```

Comment: You can compute the sum of squares a bit faster using `np.dot`: `diff = (arr - mean); diff.dot(diff)`